# Why i and books are not defined in my JavaScript closure?

Tags: javascript

Why i and books are not defined? Please explain the variable scope and liftime.

[image: here is more information]

```
            db.books.find({}, function(err, books) {

            for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
                var book = books[i];
                user.cart.forEach(function(item) {
                 console.log(book._id == item.id)

                    if (item.id == book._id) {
                        var _item = book;
                        _item.qty = item.qty;
                        cart.push(_item);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            };
            // res, status, data, message, err
            respHandler(res, 200, cart, 'Success', null);
        });
```

Comment: Books can be a null value which returns undefined when you try to access `books[i]`. How did you called `db.books.find` method? Is that parameters an undefined before this method is called?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please don't post code as images.

Comment: ok. no error ,i just cant understand why 'i' and 'books' are not definded when excuting forEach's callback

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.findOne({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            // res, status, data, message, err
            respHandler(res, 500, null, 'Oops something went wrong', err);
            return;
        }

        user.cart = user.cart || [];

        db.books.find({}, function(err, books) {
     //You create i here
            for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) { //i=alive
                var book = books[i];                 //i=alive
                user.cart.forEach(function(item) {   //i=alive
                                //do something       //i=should be alive
                })                                   //i=should still be alive
            }; //i dies
            // res, status, data, message, err
            respHandler(res, 200, cart, 'Success', null);
        });


    });
```

And about the books, i cant tell since i dont know how you manage your callback functions. Could i see "db.books.find" For more info?